# How can I install "sudo" without root access in termux?

Tags: software-installation, sudo, root, android

I am using `termux` Linux emulator. I tried most of the Linux commands and most of it worked but when I tried `sudo` it shows

```
No superuser binary detected.
Are you rooted?
```

I think it needs the device rooted. How can I run `sudo` without `root` in `termux` Android Linux emulator?

Comment: Termux website states that the app is a terminal emulator with linux environment ... that means that the commands are run in android, so any android security applies

Comment: Conceptually, if you could install `sudo` without root permissions, that would be a terrible security issue.